# How to integrate SOAP API in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I have created shopping website using magento.

Now I want to create Magento Mobile App for same website.

For integrate magento with SOAP API I have write following code :

```
<?php
try
{
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://192.168.1.199:8086/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
    $sessionId = $proxy->login(array('username' => 'myusername', 'apiKey' => 'mypassword')); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary
    $result = $proxy->catalogCategoryTree($sessionId);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
}
```

This code working on live server but not on my local server and return exception as following :

```
object(SoapFault)#2 (9) { ["message":protected]=> string(11) "Bad Request" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(36) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mobile_action.php" ["line":protected]=> int(119) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(4) { [0]=> array(4) { ["function"]=> string(11) "__doRequest" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(5) { [0]=> string(692) " df03544f48da6b56fe465c4ad347c22f113 " [1]=> string(54) "http://192.168.1.199:8086/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/" [2]=> string(10) "urn:Action" [3]=> int(1) [4]=> int(0) } } [1]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(36) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mobile_action.php" ["line"]=> int(119) ["function"]=> string(6) "__call" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(20) "catalogCategoryLevel" [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(32) "df03544f48da6b56fe465c4ad347c22f" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "3" } } } [2]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(36) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mobile_action.php" ["line"]=> int(119) ["function"]=> string(20) "catalogCategoryLevel" ["class"]=> string(10) "SoapClient" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(32) "df03544f48da6b56fe465c4ad347c22f" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "3" } } [3]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(36) "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mobile_action.php" ["line"]=> int(42) ["function"]=> string(17) "getMainCategories" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(SoapClient)#1 (5) { ["_soap_version"]=> int(1) ["sdl"]=> resource(5) of type (Unknown) ["httpurl"]=> resource(8) of type (Unknown) ["_cookies"]=> array(1) { ["PHPSESSID"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(26) "mf57nunfbuj8k1q1cjsi8gktr0" [1]=> string(1) "/" [2]=> string(13) "192.168.1.199" } } ["__soap_fault"]=> *RECURSION* } [1]=> &string(32) "df03544f48da6b56fe465c4ad347c22f" } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL ["faultstring"]=> string(11) "Bad Request" ["faultcode"]=> string(4) "HTTP" }
```

Please tell me How to integrate SOAP API v2 with local server in magento?

Is there another way to Create API for Mobile APP?

Comment: your exception log is not related to SOAP API

Comment: check magento SOAP example [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have created magento API from this url, but when calling any function it returns either `bad request` or `Parsing Schema` error.

Comment: http://192.168.1.199:8086 this is live domain ?

Comment: No this is local Server.

Comment: That might be the issue .i am not sure try with localhost

Comment: Thank you @Minesh Patel, after moving to live server its working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30369/discussion-between-minesh-patel-and-vinaya-maheshwari).

Answer (score 1):

Try this login require direct parameter not in array

```
<?php
try
{
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://192.168.1.199:8086/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('myusername','mypassword'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary
    $result = $proxy->catalogCategoryTree($sessionId);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    var_dump($e);
}
```